# Написать триггер MSSQL, который срабатывает каждый день (год, месяц)

Tags: sql, триггер

Возможно ли, и как написать триггер MSSQL, который срабатывает каждый день (год, месяц)?
Нигде не могу найти инфы.

Comment: НЕТ. Триггер срабатывает только на некие действия с данными. Наступление некоего времени к таковым не относится.

Comment: Используйте задания (job) для этого: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: В общем, я решил еще одним способом - через планировщик заданий (работал на винде). Если установлен MS SQL Express, задания (job) сделать невозможно в этой версии. А вот через планировщик заданий винды сработает точно.